# I have to run adb connect 192.168.56.101:5555 in order for android emulator to show up in list

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, genymotion

When I start a Genymotion emulator (Android studio emulators crash android studio and dont start), I have to run `adb connect 192.168.56.101:5555` in order to connect adb to the emulator. Otherwise it doesn't show up when I use `adb devices`. I never had to do this before and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Does running `adb usb` to reset adb back to its default help? Give it a try.

Comment: no that didn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with recent update in android sdk platform tools. Downgraded mine from 28.0.2 to 28.0.1 and successfully got my genymotion emulator in `adb devices` back.

Answer (score 0):

#### ***1): Try go to SDK MANAGER in folder EXTRAS and install GOOGLE USB DRIVER***

- If this happens on a Linux machine you could try to Uncheck the "Use Host GPU" checkbox - in the emulator settings**